# how to select single item OR all items in ms Access 2007 combo box

Tags: ms-access

I need your help. I have a small database in ms Access 2007. Here is the scene.
I have 1 combo box to select Company Name...........  this is working OK
Upon company selected it display Region Name.......... this is also working OK
Upon Region Selection it display Territory Name....... this is also working OK
and I get the data of Required Territory.
Now I want to Add "*" to Select All Territory. I dont know how to do it...

If any one can help me..... Thanks in advance.
Irshad Ahmed Malik

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you need to put an `All` or `*` option in your combobox (or the table/query from the comboboxs data source) manually and if someone selects `All` you need to manually catch this case and execute your desired option.